# Program freezes when incrementing/decrementing value using modulo. Possible source is low memory?

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno, arduino-ide

I have connected an 1.3in OLED display that uses I2C to my Arduino Uno plus two buttons using pullup resistors to act as "Previous" and "Next" arrows that switch between different images. I use the **u8g2** library to communicate with and draw stuff on the screen:

```
#include <U8g2lib.h>
#include <Wire.h>

#define MAX_STATES 9

U8G2_SH1106_128X64_NONAME_F_HW_I2C u8g2(U8G2_R0, U8X8_PIN_NONE);
const char COPYRIGHT_SYMBOL[] = {0xa9, '\0'};

void u8g2_prepare() {
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_6x10_tf);
  u8g2.setFontRefHeightExtendedText();
  u8g2.setDrawColor(1);
  u8g2.setFontPosTop();
  u8g2.setFontDirection(0);
}

void u8g2_box_frame() {
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 0, "drawBox");
  u8g2.drawBox(5, 10, 20, 10);
  u8g2.drawStr(60, 0, "drawFrame");
  u8g2.drawFrame(65, 10, 20, 10);
}

void u8g2_r_frame_box() {
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 0, "drawRFrame");
  u8g2.drawRFrame(5, 10, 40, 15, 3);
  u8g2.drawStr(70, 0, "drawRBox");
  u8g2.drawRBox(70, 10, 25, 15, 3);
}
void u8g2_disc_circle() {
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 0, "drawDisc");
  u8g2.drawDisc(10, 18, 9);
  u8g2.drawStr(60, 0, "drawCircle");
  u8g2.drawCircle(70, 18, 9);
}

void u8g2_string_orientation() {
  u8g2.setFontDirection(0);
  u8g2.drawStr(5, 15, "0");
  u8g2.setFontDirection(3);
  u8g2.drawStr(40, 25, "90");
  u8g2.setFontDirection(2);
  u8g2.drawStr(75, 15, "180");
  u8g2.setFontDirection(1);
  u8g2.drawStr(100, 10, "270");
}

void u8g2_line() {
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 0, "drawLine");
  u8g2.drawLine(7, 20, 77, 32);
}

void u8g2_triangle() {
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 0, "drawTriangle");
  u8g2.drawTriangle(14, 20, 45, 30, 10, 32);
}

void u8g2_unicode() {
  u8g2.drawStr(0, 0, "Unicode");
  u8g2.setFont(u8g2_font_unifont_t_symbols);
  u8g2.setFontPosTop();
  u8g2.setFontDirection(0);
  u8g2.drawUTF8(10, 20, "☀");
  u8g2.drawUTF8(30, 20, "☁");
  u8g2.drawUTF8(50, 20, "☂");
  u8g2.drawUTF8(70, 20, "☔");
  u8g2.drawUTF8(95, 20, COPYRIGHT_SYMBOL); //COPYRIGHT SIMBOL
  u8g2.drawUTF8(115, 15, "\xb0"); // DEGREE SYMBOL
}

#define image_width 128
#define image_height 21
static const unsigned char image_bits[] U8X8_PROGMEM = {
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00,
  0xfc, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0xfe, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x7f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x0c, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x06, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x03, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0xc0, 0xf0, 0x1f, 0x06, 0x63, 0x80, 0xf1,
  0x1f, 0xfc, 0x33, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0c, 0xc0, 0xf8, 0x3f,
  0x06, 0x63, 0xc0, 0xf9, 0x3f, 0xfe, 0x33, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x0c, 0xc0, 0x18, 0x30, 0x06, 0x63, 0xc0, 0x18, 0x30, 0x06, 0x30, 0xc0,
  0xff, 0xff, 0xdf, 0xff, 0x0c, 0xc0, 0x18, 0x30, 0x06, 0x63, 0xe0, 0x18,
  0x30, 0x06, 0x30, 0xc0, 0xff, 0xff, 0xdf, 0xff, 0x0c, 0xc0, 0x98, 0x3f,
  0x06, 0x63, 0x60, 0x98, 0x3f, 0x06, 0x30, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x18, 0x0c, 0x00,
  0x0c, 0xc0, 0x98, 0x1f, 0x06, 0x63, 0x70, 0x98, 0x1f, 0x06, 0x30, 0xc0,
  0x03, 0x18, 0x06, 0x00, 0x0c, 0xc0, 0x18, 0x00, 0x06, 0x63, 0x38, 0x18,
  0x00, 0x06, 0x30, 0xc0, 0x03, 0x18, 0x03, 0x00, 0x0c, 0xe0, 0x18, 0x00,
  0x06, 0x63, 0x1c, 0x18, 0x00, 0x06, 0x30, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x80, 0x01, 0x00,
  0xfc, 0x7f, 0xf8, 0x07, 0x1e, 0xe3, 0x0f, 0xf8, 0x07, 0x06, 0xf0, 0xcf,
  0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x3f, 0xf0, 0x07, 0x1c, 0xe3, 0x07, 0xf0,
  0x07, 0x06, 0xe0, 0xcf, 0x00, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0, 0x00, 0x30, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xc0,
  0x00, 0x18, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xe0, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x1f, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7f, 0x00, 0xfc, 0x1f, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x3f
};

void u8g2_bitmap() {
  u8g2.drawXBMP(0, 5, image_width, image_height, image_bits);
}
void setup(void) {
  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(7, INPUT_PULLUP);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  u8g2.begin();
  u8g2_prepare();
}

float i = 0.0;
int state = 0;

typedef struct Button
{
  char state_old;
  char state_new;
  bool pressed;

  Button ()
  {
    state_old = LOW;
    state_new = LOW;

    pressed = false;
  }
} Button;

Button prevButton;
Button nextButton;

void loop(void) {
  prevButton.state_new = digitalRead(8);
  nextButton.state_new = digitalRead(7);

  if (prevButton.state_new != prevButton.state_old)
  {
    prevButton.pressed = prevButton.state_new == LOW;
    if (prevButton.pressed)
    {
      Serial.println("Previous");
      state = ((state - 1) + MAX_STATES) % MAX_STATES;
    }
  }

  if (nextButton.state_new != nextButton.state_old)
  {
    nextButton.pressed = nextButton.state_new == LOW;
    if (nextButton.pressed)
    {
      Serial.println("Next");
      state = (state + 1) % MAX_STATES;
    }
  }

  prevButton.state_old = prevButton.state_new;
  nextButton.state_old = nextButton.state_new;

  switch (state)
  {
    case 0:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_prepare();
      u8g2_box_frame();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 1:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_disc_circle();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 2:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_r_frame_box();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 3:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_prepare();
      u8g2_string_orientation();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 4:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_line();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 5:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_triangle();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 6:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_prepare();
      u8g2_unicode();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 7:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2_bitmap();
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
    case 8:
      u8g2.clearBuffer();
      u8g2.setCursor(0, 0);
      u8g2.print(i);
      i = i + 1.5;
      u8g2.sendBuffer();
      break;
  }

  Serial.print("Current state:");
  Serial.println(state);

  delay(100);
}
```

The issue doesn't (at least I think) come from the library itself. As you can see I have created a very simple sequence of states that I switch between using the buttons. The previous button decrements, while the next - increments the state. Of course since I want to have a wrap-around behaviour (going one state more after last state will change the state to the lowest one and vice versa) I use modulo.

It works...To some extent. When I reach state 0 (lowest state) and press the previous button I expect "Current state: 8" to be displayed in the serial monitor and the respective image data to be loaded in the buffer of the OLED. Instead I get the following behaviour:

- I get output in the serial monitor:

  ```
  Pre?
  ```
- The OLED doesn't change it's buffer to the last state
- The application stops working

With stop working I mean I can neither increment, nor decrement the state using the button and the continious output "Current state: ..." is not printed. I actually just checked and the same issue happens with the increment.

I have used such modulo many times so I am very perplexed as to why this is happening. I can understand to get (for some reason) the incorrect state but for the whole thing to freeze...

One thing I've noticed when flashing the microcontroller is a warning in the Arduino IDE:

> Sketch uses 24852 bytes (77%) of program storage space. Maximum is 32256 bytes.
>
> Global variables use 1945 bytes (94%) of dynamic memory, leaving 103 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 2048 bytes.
>
> **Low memory available, stability problems may occur.**

Is it possible that this is what is happening? If so, how is it related to a simple decrement of an integer?

Answer (score 0):

I put the wrong value in `MAX_STATES`. It should be 8.

Comment: `(state+1) % 8` results in a value 0 .. 7 only. sure, this is what you want?

Comment: You are right. Do you have a solution? 9 is too much. 8 is too little. :D I will delete my answer once another one is posted.

Answer (score 0):

Modulo division is rather expensive, so let's do simply:

```
const byte STATECOUNT = 9;
static byte state; // 9 values (range 0 .. 8) circular
if (buttonup) {
 state++;
 if (state >= STATECOUNT) state = 0;
} 
else if(buttondn){
  if (state == 0) state = STATECOUNT;
  state--; 
}
```

Comment: I agree that it is expensive but that still doesn't explain the behaviour I've described. PS: Thanks for the `byte` tip. I didn't know there is such type since I'm new to Arduino. :)

Comment: uint8_t is hard to spell. And in reality, `byte` is even a more "natural integer" data type for small avr arduinos than `int`

Comment: That might be so but your solution (I've tried it) doesn't work. I'm still getting the same issue.